# Flask SQLALCHEMY setting a user.is_active = True ends up as None

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy

```
def log():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and login_form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=login_form.login.data, password=login_form.password.data).first()
        print(f"{user.is_active} before before")
        if user != None:
            print(f"{user} {user.username} b")
            print(f"{user.is_active} before")
            user.is_active = True #ends up as 'None'
            print(f"{user} {user.username} a")
            print(f"{user.is_active} after ")
            try:
                db.session.commit()
                login_user(user) 
            except Exception as e:
                db.session.rollback()  
                print(f"Error updating user: {e}")
            return render_template('test.html', test = login_user(user))
        return f"{login_form.login.data}   {login_form.password.data}  /{user}"
    return "nothing"
```

This is my models.py

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(40), unique = True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(33))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(36))
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable = False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = lambda: datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), nullable = False)
    date_last_active = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = lambda: datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), nullable = False)
```

after running the log() function

**False before before**

**<User 1> Morddy b**

**False before**

**<User 1> Morddy a**

**None after**

**Error updating user: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "is_active" of relation "user" violates not-null constraint**
**DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, Morddy, ********, nice, null, null, null, 2023-12-20 20:24:41, 2023-12-20 20:24:41).**

**[SQL: UPDATE "user" SET is_active=%(is_active)s WHERE "user".id = %(user_id)s]**
**[parameters: {'is_active': None, 'user_id': 1}]**
**(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)**

I'm using PostgreSQL 16 and after debugging i found nothing wrong, where can the problem be ?

I debugged bunch of times, restarted, tried strings and everything, but nothing worked, after running user.is_active = True it always ended up as None. After checking pgAdmin, rows were selected correctly but nothing changed.

Edit: Output from `psql <your-db-name> -c '\d user'`

```
                                          Tabulka "public.user"
     Sloupec      |             Typ             | Collation | Nullable |            Implicitne
------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id               | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)
 username         | character varying(100)      |           | not null |
 password         | character varying(60)       |           | not null |
 email            | character varying(40)       |           |          |
 first_name       | character varying(33)       |           |          |
 last_name        | character varying(36)       |           |          |
 is_active        | boolean                     |           | not null |
 date_created     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 date_last_active | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
Indexy:
    "user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "user_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
```

Comment: Did you add the `default=False` after you had created the table?  Alternatively, what's the output of `psql <your-db-name> -c '\d user'`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb everything was created at once, and in the pgAdmin the value is already 'False' in all rows. The output is in the post. Thanks

Comment: 1) Per [Query](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.model.Model.query): *The query interface is considered legacy in SQLAlchemy. Prefer using session.execute(select()) instead.* 2) [Query](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.query.Query): From what I see you are returning a result set not the `User` object, see [Modifying/Query](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/queries/).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the tip. I will try using the newer interface. Will keep you updated

Comment: Issue still persists even after using the newer interface.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the event listener for is_active that didn't return anything, after returning the value it works as expected.